# WordPress and Ocean Extra plugin ... need to get rid of a Hero Header, I think?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I hope I am in the right place, and apologize if not.

Noob here, dumped into the deep end of the WordPress pool. I inherited a website created with Elementor and OceanWP. I'm learning, but have a long way to go. I am the most technical person available to work on this, sadly. And it appears a number of people have worked on the site before in years past. I have no contact with any of them.

Recently I activated the plugin Ocean Extra (it was already installed, but deactivated) and discovered that a number of pages on the site change to include a large banner image with text over the top only when Ocean Extra is active.

Here's a page from our staging site with Ocean Extra deactivated:

[Staging site without Ocean Extra activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPRb7.png)

And here's the same page with Ocean Extra active:

[Staging site with Ocean Extra active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oh8l.jpg)

The large image with text on it is the problem. I can't find anything, anywhere, about how to edit or remove it, despite a lot of searching around, both online and in the various menus and options in Wordpress, Elementor, and OceanWP.

The closest I have found is here:

https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/495-how-to-replicate-the-theme-screenshot

which tells me this thing might be called a Hero Header, but when I try to follow the directions to edit or remove it, I can find no trace of it anywhere in WordPress. As a result I am honestly not even sure the image and text in question really are a "Hero Header". They might be something else and I am not even searching for the right thing.

Any advice on where to go looking for this image and text in the various WordPress/Elementor/OceanWP/Ocean Extra menus and configuration options would be a huge help.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: fix a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this question over on WordPress.org and I got an answer there. I will include what I was told here so anyone else who finds this question useful gets an answer.

Someone named Abishek at WordPress.org responded:

> That is the page title section and there 2 ways to customize that
> section.
>
> 1. Go to Appearance > Customize > General Options > Page Title, from here you can disable the background title image or customize it
>    according to need. This is a global setting.
> 2. another option is to edit the page in WordPress scroll down at the title tab in the oceanwp settings section, here you can change the
>    style and also can remove that background image. This is a page-level
>    settings, so you need to check each separately.

His first answer is the same as I had already seen, and didn't work for me. I find nothing about the background image when viewing the customizer on the pages in question.

His second answer, however, did help. Editing the page with the WP page editor (not Elementor!) lets me find a Title tab, where I found the background image and could change it, put things into the default state, edit the sub heading, and so on. There I could resolve all my issues with the display of this background image.

I had not tried the WP editor because the page was last edited with Elementor, and I (wrongly) assumed I shouldn't try the WP editor in that case. Mistake on my part. There's even more to find when you get into that part of the system.

I still don't understand why there are supposedly settings for the background image in the customizer as a global option. I have not seen such things. But perhaps you need to use the customizer from the home page to have them show up. Not sure, but that is for another day.

For now, this issue is definitely resolved and I can push on.